# Google Cloud Vision annotateImage feature types don't exist

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-vision

I'm trying to get more than 10 results in GC Vision with Node.js.
Since I cannot pass the custom request directly to `webDetection()` I've tried to use `annotateImage()` instead:

```
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

const webSearchRequest = {
  image: {
    source: {
      imageUri: `gs://${bucket.name}/${filePath}`
    }
  },
  features: [{
    maxResults: 50,
    type: vision.types.Feature.Type.WEB_DETECTION
  }]
};

return client.annotateImage(webSearchRequest).then(webResults => {
  console.log(webResults);
}
```

The output is `Cannot read property 'Feature' of undefined`

Comment: Try the working example here --> https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-web#vision_web_detection-nodejs

Comment: @Christopher As I said, that method only returns 10 results and you cannot pass features to get more. The documentation says that you can use annotateImage instead for these cases, but this doesn't work for me either.

Comment: I've been doing some research and using [this](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-web?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22features%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22WEB_DETECTION%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%7D%5D%2C%22image%22%3A%7B%22source%22%3A%7B%22gcsImageUri%22%3A%22gs%3A%2F%2Fcloud-samples-data%2Fvision%2Fweb%2Fcarnaval.jpeg%22%7D%7D%2C%22imageContext%22%3A%7B%22webDetectionParams%22%3A%7B%22includeGeoResults%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D#try_it)
testing tool, I've seen that the `type` attribute should be as follow: `type: WEB_DETECTION`

Comment: Are you following any tutorial? If so, could you please share it in you question?

Comment: @Miguel it works, thanks. I was following this api: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/vision/latest/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.html#annotateImage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For visibility purpose I am posting [my solution from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57853564/google-cloud-vision-annotateimage-feature-types-dont-exist?noredirect=1#comment102137700_57853564) as an answer.

After doing some research and testing with [this](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-web?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22features%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22WEB_DETECTION%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%7D%5D%2C%22image%22%3A%7B%22source%22%3A%7B%22gcsImageUri%22%3A%22gs%3A%2F%2Fcloud-samples-data%2Fvision%2Fweb%2Fcarnaval.jpeg%22%7D%7D%2C%22imageContext%22%3A%7B%22webDetectionParams%22%3A%7B%22includeGeoResults%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D#try_it) tool I've seen that the attribute `type` should be as follow: `type: WEB_DETECTION` instead of `type: vision.types.Feature.Type.WEB_DETECTION`.